# How can I get a ToolStripDropDownButton to align to the right edge of a StatusStrip?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, statusstrip, toolstripbutton, toolstripdropdown

I don't see a likely property on either the StatusStrip or the ToolStripDropDownButton - other than the Alignment property of the ToolStripDropDownButton, which doesn't help.

Will I have to add "shims"/spacers or some such to elbow the ToolStripDropDownButton away from the left edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I added a toolStripStatusLabel, and set its Spring property to True and its Text property to [blank].

It works, so I guess it's good...